# A segunda QUERY do Store Procedure não roda... não achei o bug

Tags: php

A segunda seleção do Store Procedure não roda... não achei o bug...

```
<? require("viskoo_conexao/conectar.php");?>


<?php

$consulta="CALL SPMenuConsulta";

$resultado = mysql_query($consulta)

or die("Falha na SP (1)");

?>




<?php

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado))

{

$ValorAtributo = $linha[ValorAtributo];

$CodAtributoValor = $linha[CodAtributoValor];


echo $ValorAtributo." ($CodAtributoValor)<br>";

?>
        <? $resultado2 = mysql_query( 'CALL SpMenuSubConsulta(5)' ) or die(mysql_error()); ?>

        <?php
        while ($linha2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado2))
        {
        $ValorAtributo = $linha2["ValorAtributo"];
        echo "--Sub".$ValorAtributo."<br>";
        }
        ?>

<?

}

?>
```

Comment: Pessoal não perdoa, 1 minuto e 2 negativos. Deviam usar esse esforço pra ajudar, mas enfim. Não entendi pq vc esta usando CALL SpMenuSubConsulta(5) em uma query. Pode explicar?

Comment: Um possível problema é o uso das funções obsoletas `mysql_*` que não trabalham corretamente com SP.

Comment: Hum? não entendi os primeiros comentários rs sim. Seguinte... eu preciso de 2 seleções nesse caso, pego os dados de uma SP e uso em outra SP com o while

Comment: E qual poderia utilizar no lugar? @rray

Comment: Qual erro aparece? é algo como out sync?

Comment: Exatamente @rray "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Comment: Da pra resolver de algumas formas, se não possível trocar as funções pelo `MySQLi` ou PDO pode armazenar o resultado da primeira SP em um array depois fazer um foreach com ele e chamar a segunda dentro, talvez tenha outra forma mas essas são as que lembro agora xD

Comment: Já tá ótimo brother @rray eu vou testar esses dois, resolvendo volto a publicar a resolução!! tks, obrigado brothers

Comment: Diego, Eu penso a mesma coisa cara, Se eles usassem isso para ajudar seria muito mais produtivo, parece que eles já acostumaram a negativar tudo, eu fiz uma pergunta e em alguns minutos tiveram 2 negativos e logo depois subiu para 2 positivo e 2 resposta cada uma com 1 postivo... Agora pensa... Aqueles que negativam eles negativam por quê?? se a pergunta estava dentro dos conforme e ganhou positividade?? tá vendo? tem algo muito errado nisso o povo prefere só atrapalhar ao invés de ajudar.

Comment: Entendi agora rs Diego! realmente rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother, resolvi o problema usando um ARRAY, olha só! deu certinho!

```
                <?php
                $ArrayMenuAtr = array();

                    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'loja', 'Pass', 'loja' );
                    $result = $mysqli->query("CALL SPMenuConsulta()");

                    if( !$result ) {

                        die('Query failed returning error: '. $mysqli->connect_errno );

                    } else {

                        while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                            $ValorAtributo        =  $row['ValorAtributo'];
                            $CodAtributoValor        =  $row['CodAtributoValor'];

                            $ArrayMenuAtr[$CodAtributoValor] = $ValorAtributo;

                        }
                    }
                ?>



                <?

                foreach ($ArrayMenuAtr as $id => $categoria):

                echo "Menu: $categoria ($id) <br>";

                $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'loja', 'Pass', 'loja' );
                    $result = $mysqli->query("CALL SpMenuSubConsulta($id)");

                    if( !$result ) {

                        die('Query failed returning error: '. $mysqli->connect_errno );

                    } else {

                        while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                            $ValorAtributo        =  $row['ValorAtributo'];

                            echo "Sub- ".$ValorAtributo."<br>";
                        }
                    }

                endforeach


                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Esse erro acontece geralmente ao utilizar stored procedures com as funções `mysql_*`, a mensagem diz algo como "não posso processar essa consulta porque ainda não terminei de tratar a anterior."

O ideal é migrar o código das funções `mysql_*` para as do MySQLi, se isso não for possível, faça o processamento da primeira consulta e armazena em um array e depois itere ele chame a segunda stored procedure.

```
<?php
   $consulta="CALL SPMenuConsulta";
   $resultado = mysql_query($consulta) or die("Falha na SP (1)". mysql_error());

   $arr = array();
   while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ 
      $arr[] = $linha;
   }

   foreach($arr as $item){  
      $ValorAtributo = $item['ValorAtributo'];
      $CodAtributoValor = $item['CodAtributoValor'];
      $resultado2 = mysql_query( 'CALL SpMenuSubConsulta(5)') or die(mysql_error());
      while ($linha2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado2)){
         $ValorAtributo = $linha2["ValorAtributo"];
         echo "--Sub".$ValorAtributo."<br>";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Estranho, tentei e retornou o mesmo erro "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Comment: No Lugar no (5) eu gostaria de pegar o valor de $CodAtributoValor -- `CALL SpMenuSubConsulta($CodAtributoValor)´

Comment: @JosiasViskoo deu erro? em teoria é a mesma coisas

Comment: Aparentemente deu erro também... talvez exista alguma alternativa diferente para fazer o que estou pensando em fazer... talvez essa prática é errada... porque na web e no manual não tem nada do tipo... o que eu estou tentando fazer é um menu e submenu a partir de uma consulta variante. A Primeira SP retorna categorias e a segunda SP retorna os IDs das categorias que trazem outros subcategorias, pensei em fazer na mesma SP, mas utilizarei essa SP em outras páginas...

Comment: @JosiasViskoo mesmo executando a primeira consulta em um while da o out of sync?

Comment: Sim, deu o mesmo erro... estranho... até individuais também acontece isso, mas a diferença entre eles é que uma é parametrizada e outra não... talvez o mysql_query não suporta SP com parâmetro, será?

Comment: @JosiasViskoo o problema é que você tenta executar a segunda consulta sem ter acabado de tratar a primeira, to vendo aqui outras coisas ...

Comment: Hum entendi... pelo que entendi é isso, mas não consegui tratar essa questão nessa possibilidade... @rray